# ASP.NET AJAX Controls : UpdatePanel & UpdateProgress

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

It seems UpdateProgress will be displayed covering the entire area of the UpdatePanel.

I want to replicate this behavior using plain javascript, as this behavior needs to be done for a windows client form.

Are there any javascript libraries available?

Thanks.

EDIT : I am using a Browser control inside windows client form to get results and render them.

Answer (score 2):

Umm ... you won't be able to use javascript for a windows client form. You will need to approximate the behavior using the provided windows forms controls like the progress bar

Comment: +1.  How is it you're the only one who answered who caught that? ;-)

Comment: I guess this makes a difference. I am using a Browser control inside windows client form to get results and render them.

Comment: If that's the case, why wouldn't the built in updatepanel work? does the browsercontrol not execute javascript? because if it does then the updatepanel and updateprogress should just work as designed :-)

Comment: I guess I messed up the way I put in the question. Once the results are rendered, there is no async post back. The progress bar should be displayed when a sort button is clicked. Sort is done using javascript. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the JavaScript library [**JQuery**](http://jquery.com/) and [**JQueryUI**](http://jqueryui.com/)'s [**ProgressBar**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar).